# closing WCF proxy

Tags: wcf

I have always followed the guidance of try/Close/catch/Abort when it comes to a WCF proxy. I am facing a code base now that creates proxies in MVC controllers and just lets them go out of scope. I'm arguing the case that we need to edit the code base to use try/Close/catch/Abort but there is resistance.

Does anyone know a metric (e.g. perfmon) I can capture to illustrate the problem/benefit. Or a definitive reference that spells out the problem/benefit no one can dispute?

Comment: You also need to argue that you should not be creating WCF proxies in controllers.

Comment: ChrisBint: What is your objection to creating proxies in controllers?

Comment: @JohnC Give then nature of this question about wrapping proxy interaction into a suitable try/catch/abort, it will inevitably end up with a fairly sizeable section of code that would ideally be placed in it's another location and called from the Controller. It's not really an objection, more a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sample application to mimic the problem. Though I haven't tried you can try this,

1. Create a simple service and limit the `maxConcurrentCalls` and `maxConcurrentSessions` to 5.
2. Create a client application and in that, call the service method without closing the connection.
3. Fire up 6 or more clients
4. See what happens when you open a new connection from a client. Probably the client will wait for certain time and you get some exception.

If the client don't close the connection properly, the connection will still remain open in the service so what happens if 1000s of client connected to the service at a time and leave their connections open? The service has a limitation that it could server 'n' connections at a time and because of that the service can't handle any new requests from clients and that's why closing connections are very important.

I think you are aware about the [`using`](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/03/WCF-Dispose) problem in WCF service. In my applications I close the WCF connections using an extension method as said in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000736/is-it-correct-to-implement-idisposable-on-singleton/13013904#13013904).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simple 'netstat -N' from the command prompt both on server and client? Yoy are likely to see a lot of waiting/pending connections which might exhaust your server resources for no reason.