# Is it correct to implement IDisposable on Singleton

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns

In our WCF project, we are using `singleton pattern` to obtain client proxy.

Basically because-

1. Any enhancements required later, on the client object adding
   `Binding` or `Endpoint`, would require minimal changes.
2. We do not call multiple service, at the same time.

To make sure that `connection is closed` properly after each service call, We are planning to implement `IDisposable` in singleton as below -

```
public class ClientSingleton : IDisposable
{
    static Service1Client client;
    private ClientSingleton()
    {
        client = new Service1Client();
    }
    public Service1Client getInstance()
    {
        if (client != null)
            return client;
        else
        {
            client = new Service1Client();
            return client;
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Does this violates Singleton `Design-Pattern` principles? Any advice to improve this would be helpful.

**edit:**

Consider `using block` to dispose the client object as below -

```
using (Service1Client client = new Service1Client())
{
    client.Operation1();
}
```

That means WCF proxies implement `IDisposable` interface. So I don't see any harm in implementing this interface here.

Thanks!

Comment: I may be wrong but i do not see you closing connection it seems like you trying to reference/create new connection instead of closing the original one

Comment: So where is your implementation of IDisposable?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Added code here.

Comment: You mean a Factory? This is not a Singleton...

Comment: I don't think this should be a singleton.

Comment: I think indeed you want to have a factory. IDisposable is for unmanaged resources you want to get rid of. And disposing/closing the proxy and then getting another instance may cause troubles in the current code. Even though you might have disposed of the object, it has a high chance of not being null.

Comment: IDisposable is not just for unmanaged resources. I think you mean finalisers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using an extension method in my project that takes care of closing the service connection properly. (I stole the extension method from some blog and I forgot that blog link)

```
public static void CloseConnection(this ICommunicationObject client)
{
  if (client.State != CommunicationState.Opened)
  {
    return;
  }

  try
  {
    client.Close();
  }
  catch (CommunicationException)
  {
    client.Abort();
    throw;
  }
  catch (TimeoutException)
  {
    client.Abort();
    throw;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    client.Abort();
    throw;
  }
}
```

Unlike your approach (which is specific to a particular proxy) this can be used on any proxy to close the connection safely.

Example usage

```
Service1Client client = null

try
{
  client = new Service1Client();
}
finally
{
  if(client != null)
     client.CloseConnection();
}
```